# VBA transferring data to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

[image: VBA transfer data from one sheet to another]

In the attached picture, this is the end goal.

I would like to transfer data from one sheet to another sheet using VBA. 
So far, when I click "Submit", the data for Country, Name, Surname will be sent correctly to the sheet named "data". However, I am unsure how to populate the "Race" field in the sheet named "data". I understand that I should be using an if statement, but i'm not sure how to incorporate it into the VBA code.

This is the vba code at the moment.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

     Dim Country As String, Name As String, Surname As String, Race As String
     Worksheets("form").Select

     Country = Range("B4")
     Name = Range("B6")
     Surname = Range("B7")
     Race = Range("B13")

     Worksheets("data").Select
     Worksheets("data").Range("A1").Select
     If Worksheets("data").Range("A1").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
          Worksheets("data").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
     End If

     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     ActiveCell.Value = Country
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
     ActiveCell.Value = Name
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
     ActiveCell.Value = Surname
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
     ActiveCell.Value = Race

     Worksheets("form").Select
     Worksheets("form").Range("A4").Select
End Sub
```

I am new to VBA, any assistance with this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something for you, however i have some critique for you

1) Selecting/Activating/Copy/Pasting are all bad habits. You end up writing tons of pointless code to get any use out of it and you slow down the entire prcoess. This matters if there's tons of things youre interacting with.

2). Race on the form tab looks to be a merged cell. my code snippet here is working under the assumption that race is in fact cells b13, c13 and d13. Merged cells are annoying, and might be the under lying cause to your issue. OR i could be totally wrong and you really are super new. Either way youre learning something.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     Dim Country As String, Name As String, Surname As String, Race As String
     dim ws as worksheet, wb as workbook, ws1 as worksheet

     set wb = ThisWorkbook
     set ws = wb.Sheets("form")
     set ws1 = wb.Sheets("data")
     Country = ws.Range("B4").value
     Name = ws.Range("B6").value
     Surname = ws.Range("B7").value

     If ws.Range("B13").Value <> "" Then Race = "White"
     If ws.Range("C13").Value <> "" Then Race = "Black"
     If ws.Range("D13").Value <> "" Then Race = "Asian"

     ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Value = Country
     ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Offset(0,1).Value = Name
     ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Offset(0,2).Value = Surname
     ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Offset(0,3).Value = Race
End Sub
```

I actually kind of like this better, less variables. Instead of using pointless variables to store values you could just store the values in an array and move them all over at once, which i also think saves on over head. *Granted* I understand I used the same amount fo variables to make sheets/workbooks objects but you could write them out the long way (i actually prefer to do that even though its a blanket of text at that point).

I also included some checks just in case more than one race was chosen, or none at all.

```
Private Sub here()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim arr(0, 4) As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    arr(0, 0) = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Value + 1
    arr(0, 1) = ws.Range("B4").Value
    arr(0, 2) = ws.Range("B6").Value
    arr(0, 3) = ws.Range("B7").Value

    If (ws.Range("B13").Value <> "" And ws.Range("C13").Value <> "") _
        Or (ws.Range("B13").Value <> "" And ws.Range("D13").Value <> "") _
            Or (ws.Range("D13").Value <> "" And ws.Range("C13").Value <> "") Then
        arr(0, 4) = "Mixed Race"
    Else
        arr(0, 4) = IIf(ws.Range("B13").Value <> "", "White", _
            IIf(ws.Range("C13").Value <> "", "Black", _
                IIf(ws.Range("D13").Value <> "", "Asian", "Must Be Non-Human")))
    End If

    ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1), _
        ws1.Cells(ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 5)).Value2 = arr

End Sub
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your critique and will learn from it. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing me with another approach for solving the problem. 
May I please ask you one more question. If I wanted to provide an extra column field in cell "A1". This field will denote the index number for each new entry populated in the sheet "data". How would I go about that?

Comment: @ALK Easily ;) enjoy

Comment: When I try running the code, it says I have a type mismatch ...:/

Comment: @ALK Idk whats going on on your end but it works perfectly for me.

Comment: I'm not sure either. But thank you very much for all your assistance. Really appreciate it @Doug Coats